# How to extract unconnected structures from noise-generated image?

Tags: java, image-processing, pattern-recognition, perlin-noise

I'm working on a map generator for a strategy browser game. The goal is to have randomly generated islands with height information.

I am using Perlin Noise to get these random structures representing islands:

[Image of islands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsH3W.png)

For the game I need each island as an individual image. So basically I am looking for a way to "cut" out each white island that is not connected to another one.

Note that the solution must not use the image representation but could as well access the noise data directly. Also this is just an example representation. If it is easier to handle this problem with a transparent background instead of a black one for example, this is possible as well.

What would be the best approach to this problem?

(As the existing backend and implementation are done in Java, this is the preferred language for a solution. I am however open for any suggestions.)

Comment: Google "connected component analysis" or "label binary image". That should lead you to algorithms to identify each of the islands.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks, that is looking promising!